# jsoup to parse atypical markup

Tags: java, jsoup

Can I use jsoup to parse non-standard markup, such as `<LOCATION>`, `<PERSON>`, or `<ORGANIZATION>`?

This is an example sentence in my corpus:

```
I HAD been hearing about vineyards in <LOCATION>Malibu</LOCATION> for some time,  
but I wrote them off. Had to be a tourist gimmick, like  
<PERSON>Knott</PERSON>'s <ORGANIZATION>Berry Farm</ORGANIZATION>  
or the LaBrea Tar Pits. <LOCATION>Malibu</LOCATION> was the playground of the stars,  
a surfers' mecca, but cabernet? No way.
```

I'd like to extract something like:

```
Location: Malibu
Person: Knott
Organization: Berry Farm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not part of the HTML specification the default `parse` method will not handle the custom markup.

You can however tell JSoup to parse it as an XML:

```
Jsoup.parse(yourHtml, baseUriForLinks, Parser.xmlParser());
```

The command above will return a `Document` in which you can operate with your custom markup.

**Where:**

`yourHtml` - the HTML with the custom markup as `String`

`baseUriForLinks` - the base URL of the HTML (so that JSoup can resolve relative links if any are present) also as `String`